# What is the best way of using normalize.css in Nuxt.js projects?

Tags: nuxt.js, normalize-css

I have scaffolded a new [Nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org) project using `npx create-nuxt-app` command and used **Bulma** for UI framework.
I learned that bulma.css file has been included in *nuxt.config.js* file with the following configuration.

```
modules: [
  '@nuxtjs/bulma'
]
```

But then I want to use [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) to make sure the styles keep consistency in all browsers. To make this work properly, this normalize.css file should be included at the top of all css files.

I have tried importing it in `layout/default.vue` file like this. (I referenced [this](https://fabiofranchino.com/blog/log/using-nuxt-and-normalize-css-to-generate-files))

```
<style lang="scss">
  @import '~/node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css'
</style>
```

But then I learned as I inspect on Chrome devtools that normalize.css file is actually included at the bottom.

[image: screenshot of element inspection on chrome devtools]

The style that is included before the normalize.css is *bulma.css*

So the question is: How can I properly import **normalize.css** in this Nuxt.js project so that it is imported/included at the top of the css file list?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In `nuxt.config.js` file, I have included **normalize.css** as a gloabal css file like below.

```
css: [
 'normalize.css/normalize.css'
],
```

And **normalize.css** styles comes before *bulma.css*, so seems like problem solved.

[image]

Comment: which folder did you put this css file inside, assets, or static?

Comment: I have installed normalize.css through npm command - `npm install normalize.css`